# XSLT - analyze following sibling of a given node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
    <doc>
    <h1>header 1</h1>
    <p>para</p>
    <p>para</p>

    <h1>header 2</h1>
    <p>para</p>
    <h2>header 2 sub h1</h2>
    <h2>header 2 sub h2</h2>

    <h1>header 3</h1>
    <p>para</p>
    <p>para</p>

    <h1>header 4</h1>
    <h2>header 4 sub h1</h2>
    <p>para</p> 

</doc>
```

what I need is get all `<h1>` and `<h2>` nodes orderly and create an unordered list,

so final output should look like this,

```
    <doc>
        <ul>
            <li><h1>header 1</h1><li>

            <li><h1>header 2</h1></li>
            <ul> 
              <li><h2>header 2 sub h1</h2></li>
              <li><h2>header 2 sub h2</h2><li>
            </ul>

            <li><h1>header 3</h1></li>

            <li><h1>header 4 sub h1</h1></li>
            <ul>
              <li><h2>zz</h2></li>
            </ul>
       </ul>
  </doc>
```

The xsl that I've written is follows,

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
        <doc>
            <xsl:for-each select="//h1">
                <li>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="//h2" group-by="count(preceding::h1)">
                        <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>
```

the result this give is follows,

```
<doc>
    <li>header 1</li>
    <ul><li>header 2 sub h1header 4 sub h1</li></ul>
    <li>header 2</li>
    <ul></li>header 2 sub h1header 4 sub h1</li></ul>
    <li>header 3</li>
    <ul></li>header 2 sub h1header 4 sub h1</li></ul>
    <li>header 4</li>
    <ul></li>header 2 sub h1header 4 sub h1</li></ul>
</doc>
```

as you can see i've used for-each groping to add the `<h2>`nodes under the related `<h1>` nodes. (this is the solution that I could think of to add `<h2>` nodes under its related `<h1>` nodes.) however as you can see it does not give the expected output.

can you suggest a way how can I change my code to get expected result. or may be another method to get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want group-starting-with for this.

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
      <li><xsl:copy-of select="."/></li>
      <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::h2]"/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Do you really want this output? In HTML all the children of a `<ul>` element must be `<li>` elements. However, as far as the XSLT is concerned, you should be able to adapt this approach.

Comment: This works perfectly +1. html might be wrong in this code. I just mede this up to explains the problem. Thanks for the answer. :)